# How do I get an notification when Rotation of my control has Changed

Tags: wpf, user-controls, rotation

The `UserControl` class offers me events like `SizeChanged`. So I can do any actions on my control when the size is changed:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded" SizeChanged="UserControl_SizeChanged">
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
    private void UserControl_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      // do anything
    }
```

Now I'd like to find out when the rotation of my control is changed, too. However, the `UserControl` class does not offer me a RotationChanged-Event.

The reason I want to track the rotation is I got some elements in my user control that I would like to rotate back, so they are always aligned to the horizontally axis / orientation of the application. (Other parent elements won't be rotated, so I don't have to care about those.)

Here is an image that illustrates the thing I want to archive a bit more: 
[image: sample]

The black box is the user control while the red box is an `UIElement` in my user control. Default state is on top. 
When the user is rotating my control (bottom sample) I want to back-rotate the element in my control. If there is no `RotationChanged` event, how else can I do it?

**EDIT:**
To the given solution of Sheridan I want to mention the event has to subscribed in the Loaded event of my user control. And in the Changed event I can simply cast to `RotateTransform` and check for null. On the initial rotation I have to try to cast this.RenderTransform to `RotateTransform` or `TransformGroup` (that children I can to loop through) at the Loaded event. On this way I get my angle.

BUT, if you are trying to archive the same as I did, there is a further problem, because the designer will override your `RenderTransform` node, thus the `RenderTransform.Changed` event will be lost. I separated it as own question here on StackOverflow: [Subscription to RenderTransform.Changed will be lost when it does not fulfill the XAML pattern of the designer on initial time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604082/subscription-to-rendertransform-changed-will-be-lost-when-it-does-not-fulfill-th)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `RotationChanged` event on the `UserControl` class because rotation is not performed by that class. Instead in WPF, rotation is performed by the [`RotationTransform` Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx). It is on that class that you can find the [`Freezable.Changed` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.changed(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
RotationTransform transform = new RotationTransform();
transform.Changed += OnRotationChanged;
```

...

```
public void OnRotationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. However I want to mention the event has to subscribed in the `Loaded` event of my user control. And in the `Changed` event I can simply cast to `RotateTransform` and check for _null_. On the initial rotation I have to try to cast `this.RenderTransform` to `RotateTransform` or `TransformGroup` (that children I can to loop through) at the `Loaded` event. On this way I get my angle, yay.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, I believe that it would be more useful to future users if you add that as an edit to the bottom of your question. (Easier to see).

Comment: I updated my question. There is also a further problem with your solution I want to handle on a new question. Please check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604082/subscription-to-rendertransform-changed-will-be-lost-when-it-does-not-fulfill-th Thank you