# Subscription to RenderTransform.Changed will be lost when it does not fulfill the XAML pattern of the designer on initial time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, user-controls

In my user control I want to get aware of rotations & co. made in the WPF designer. So in my user control I did:

```
    private void Test_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RenderTransform.Changed += this.RenderTransform_Changed;
    }

    private void RenderTransform_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do anything
    }
```

It seems `this.RenderTransform` is never *null*. However unless my user control has the exact XAML structure like the designer makes when i.e. rotating my control, it will fail.

**Example:**
When I open a XAML file with the following content:

```
<my:Test>
    <my:Test.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </my:Test.RenderTransform>
</my:Test>
```

the `RenderTransform_Changed` will be called when I rotate my control.

But when the XAML is:

```
<my:Test>
    <my:Test.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </my:Test.RenderTransform>
</my:Test>
```

or

```
<my:Test>
    <my:Test.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </my:Test.RenderTransform>
</my:Test>
```

or

```
<my:Test/>
```

it won't call `RenderTransform_Changed` when rotating my control.

I assume, this happens, because the designer is recreating `this.RotateTransform` when it does not follow the exact same structure as the designer wants. Thus, the subscription will be lost, entirely.

To solve the problem I tried to provide the same structure to `this.RenderTransform` in the `Loaded` event before subscribing to the `Changed` event:

```
    private void Test_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScaleTransform scale = this.RenderTransform is ScaleTransform 
            ? (ScaleTransform)this.RenderTransform 
            : new ScaleTransform();
        SkewTransform skew = this.RenderTransform is SkewTransform 
            ? (SkewTransform)this.RenderTransform 
            : new SkewTransform();
        RotateTransform rotate = this.RenderTransform is RotateTransform 
            ? (RotateTransform)this.RenderTransform 
            : new RotateTransform();
        TranslateTransform translate = this.RenderTransform is TranslateTransform 
            ? (TranslateTransform)this.RenderTransform 
            : new TranslateTransform();

        if (this.RenderTransform is TransformGroup)
        {
            TransformCollection tc = ((TransformGroup)this.RenderTransform).Children;

            foreach (Transform t in tc)
            {
                if (t is ScaleTransform) scale = (ScaleTransform)t;
                if (t is SkewTransform) skew = (SkewTransform)t;
                if (t is RotateTransform) rotate = (RotateTransform)t;
                if (t is TranslateTransform) translate = (TranslateTransform)t;
            }

            if (!tc.Any(x => x is ScaleTransform)) tc.Add(scale);
            if (!tc.Any(x => x is SkewTransform)) tc.Add(skew);
            if (!tc.Any(x => x is RotateTransform)) tc.Add(rotate);
            if (!tc.Any(x => x is TranslateTransform)) tc.Add(translate);
        }
        else
        {
            this.RenderTransform = new TransformGroup()
            {
                Children = 
                {
                    scale,
                    skew,
                    rotate,
                    translate,
                },
            };
        }

        foreach (Transform t in ((TransformGroup)this.RenderTransform).Children)
        {
            t.Changed += this.RenderTransform_Changed;
        }
        this.RenderTransform.Changed += this.RenderTransform_Changed;
    }

    private void RenderTransform_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do anything
    }
```

With that I tried to be ready for any given structure of `RenderTransform` on initial time. But it seems the designer does not care what's actually in the `RenderTransform` object, it simply rewrites it, because the XAML still does not fulfill the structure it wants.

What can I do to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm wrong in my diagnosis of the problem, here's an answer:

**The problem**

Whenever you register a handler with `this.RenderTransform.Changed += ...` you subscribe to an object which is the value of `this.RenderTransform`. When the property is then changed, it no longer holds the object to which you subscribed (and that object is no longer in effect), yet you're still subscribed to that exact object, and not the new value of the property.

**The solution**

In order to keep track of the actual value of the `RenderTransform` proprety you need to subscribe to it's owner (usually a `Window` or a `Control`) for a "ValueChanged" event, and register `RenderTransform.Changed` handler upon each occurrence of that event. Since `RenderTransform` is a "shortcut property" for a `DependencyProperty` called `RenderTransformProperty`, you need to do it like this:

```
//inside the constructor
{
    DependencyPropertyDescriptor
        .FromProperty(RenderTransformProperty)
        .AddValueChanged(this, new EventHandler(RenderTransformPropertyChanged));
}

private void RenderTransformPropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //this.RenderTransform.Changed += ...
}
```

where `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` is in `System.ComponendModel` namespace.

Comment: Thank you. Your solution put me in the right direction, but I solved it in another way.

Comment: I will mark you answer as the right one and I assume it would work, too. You deserve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Grx70's solution gave me the right direction, however I was overwriting the `PropertyMetadata` to get rid of the reset of `RenderTransform`.

So I did

```
        Control.RenderTransformProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Test), new PropertyMetadata(
                Control.RenderTransformProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(Test)).DefaultValue
                , new PropertyChangedCallback(Test.RenderTransform_Changed)
            )
        );
```

in the static constructor of my control. So then I could do

```
    protected static void RenderTransform_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Test obj = (Test)d; // my control
        Transform x = obj.RenderTransform; // new rendertransform
        if (x.IsFrozen == false)
        {
            x.Changed += obj.RenderTransform_Changed;
        }
        // do anything
    }
```